# Chat APP Firebase Flutter PROBLEM WITH TWO STREAM BUILDERS TO Display messages

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is displaying messages, and exactly the messages of my chat buddy appear under my messages, even when I write something new, the message will always be my friend's messages and messages.

My friend does not show up all, I think the problem is in the streamers, I do not know how to take them both to download information and at the same time for the chat to work normally

```
child: Column(children: 
[
StreamBuilder(
  stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('writer',isEqualTo: writer).snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
{
 
 if(snapshot.hasData)
 {
 return ListView.builder(
  
  shrinkWrap:true,
  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){


var w=  snapshot.data.docs[index]['ChatRoom'][writer].toList();
return Column(children: [

for ( var i in w ) 
ChatBubble(
        clipper: ChatBubbleClipper1(type: BubbleType.sendBubble),
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        backGroundColor: Colors.blue,
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
          ),
          child:Text(i)
      )

),

//my frend

StreamBuilder(
  stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('uid',isEqualTo: writer).snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){

  var w=  snapshot.data.docs[index]['ChatRoom'][writer].toList();
  for (var o in w)
return    ChatBubble(
    clipper: ChatBubbleClipper1(type: BubbleType.receiverBubble),
    backGroundColor: Color(0xffE7E7ED),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
    child: Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
      ),
      child: Text(
     w[index],
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
  );
return Center();
  }
)
],);
  },);
 }else{
   return Center(child:Text('not text yuet'));
 }
}),
      ]
      ,)
```

[image]